# Why am I forced to start typing halfway down the input box? Want to start at top and when it reaches end of box wrap to next line

Tags: html, css

[image: Image here]

```
#main {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#main #main-col {
    float: left;
    width: 68%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

#main #sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}

#main #sidebar #sidebar-message {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90%;
}

    <aside id="sidebar">
        <h3>Advice? Leave us a message!</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tellus ex, pharetra et orci sollicitudin, luctus consequat massa. Donec dapibus neque id lobortis efficitur. Morbi ultrices neque ut ipsum rhoncus mollis.</p>
        <form>
            Full name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
            Message:<br>
            <input type="text" name="message" id="sidebar-message"><br>
        </form>
    </aside>
```

Want to have user start typing at the top(like Twitter) and when it reaches end of box wrap to next line. Also want to restrict users from typing outside the box.

Comment: Um, use a `<textarea>` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used a text input which is for only one line of text. You need to use a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead.

```
   <aside id="sidebar">
        <h3>Advice? Leave us a message!</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tellus ex, pharetra et orci sollicitudin, luctus consequat massa. Donec dapibus neque id lobortis efficitur. Morbi ultrices neque ut ipsum rhoncus mollis.</p>
        <form>
            Full name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
            Message:<br>
            <textarea name="message" id="sidebar-message"></textarea><br>
        </form>
    </aside>
```